# Junit Configuration error: You must provide at least one argument for this @ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, junit, tdd, junit5

I am trying to understand JUnit 5 with the help of a FizzBuzz app with JUnit 5.
Below is one of the test case

```
@DisplayName("Test for multiples of 5")
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("multiplesOf5Inputs")
    public void multiplesOf5(Integer input){
        String result =  fizzBuzz.play(input);
        Assertions.assertEquals("Buzz",result);
    }

    private static Stream<Integer> multiplesOf5Inputs(){
        return IntStream.range(1,60)
.skip(15).skip(30).skip(45).skip(60)
                .mapToObj(i->i);
    }
```

This test case is failing to execute by throwing the following exception

```
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Configuration error: You must provide at least one argument for this @ParameterizedTest

at org.junit.platform.commons.util.Preconditions.condition(Preconditions.java:297)
at org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTestExtension.lambda$provideTestTemplateInvocationContexts$7(ParameterizedTestExtension.java:60)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.close(AbstractPipeline.java:323)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:101)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestTemplateTestDescriptor.execute(TestTemplateTestDescriptor.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:112)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

What could be the root cause?

Comment: The error seems to be pretty clear: `Configuration error: You must provide at least one argument for this @ParameterizedTest` ! In other words, where is your parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're creating a stream of 60 things and then skip more than 60 things... your stream ends up empty.

So you need to ensure that `multiplesOf5Inputs()` actually returns a non-empty stream.

Comment: Just realized that, and posted the answer 8 seconds after you :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with my understanding of the skip method.

I assumed that skip skips the specific number, however, it skips the number of elements provided as the argument.

Which means when `.skip(60)` is invoked over the range of 60 elements, all of them are skipped and there is an empty stream.

hence the error

> Configuration error: You must provide at least one argument for this
>   @ParameterizedTest
>   Change the code to

```
 @DisplayName("Test for multiples of 5")
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("multiplesOf5Inputs")
    public void multiplesOf5(int input){
        String result =  fizzBuzz.play(input);
        Assertions.assertEquals("Buzz",result);
    }

    private static Stream<Integer> multiplesOf5Inputs(){
        return IntStream.range(1,60)
                // You need filter, not skip
                .mapToObj(i->{return i*5;}).filter(i -> i%15!=0);
    }
```

Summary :
This error occurs when the number of parameters being provided by the source is 0

Comment: My opinion is that an empty set of parameters should be allowed (it was in junit 4). This happens in my software where the parameters are extremely data-driven; no parameters should really mean no tests, not a test failure. Unfortunately there is no flag or annotation to prevent junit from throwing this exception. As a workaround, I add a null value to the collection/stream so that the @ParameterizedTest method is invoked once, but quits if it gets a null parameter.